# Get existing record id from exec(@sql)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CREATE_ERROR_LOG] 
    @ERROR_MESSAGE VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @ERROR_CODE INT = 200,
    @USER_ID VARCHAR(50) = '00000',
    @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(20),
    @CONTROLLER VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @METHOD VARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID AS INT = 0,
            @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT @ID = ID  
                FROM ' + @TABLE_NAME + ' 
                WHERE CODE = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @ERROR_CODE)
                + ' AND MESSAGE = ' + @ERROR_MESSAGE 
                + ' AND USER_ID = ' + @USER_ID 
                + 'AND CONTROLLER = ' + @CONTROLLER 
                + ' AND METHOD = ' + @METHOD;

    EXEC(@SQL);
    PRINT(@ID);

    SELECT @ERROR_CODE AS Code, @ERROR_MESSAGE AS MESSAGE;
END
```

I want `ID` of existing record from a table and store it into variable `@ID`. Table name is sent in as a parameter.

I have looked at a couple of question, but found no solution.

Comment: Aside from the poor pattern of design this represents and some had habits, what exactly is your question? Mind-reading does not work so well from a distance. I will also point out that the name of your procedure has no relationship to the function it performs. Code should not lie and do things that are unexpected.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a parameterized query with an output parameter to return the @ID value back to the outer scope from the dynamic query.

Below is an annotated example with additional best practices. Note that no row will be found if any of the filter criteria parameters are `NULL`. You'll need to change the query to check of `IS NULL` in order to filter for `NULL` valaues.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CREATE_ERROR_LOG] 
    @ERROR_MESSAGE VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @ERROR_CODE INT = 200,
    @USER_ID VARCHAR(50) = '00000',
    @TABLE_NAME SYSNAME, --changed data type to match identifier type
    @CONTROLLER VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @METHOD VARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @ID AS INT = 0,
            @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX); --changed data type needed for sp_executesql

    --validate table name
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = @TABLE_NAME) 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Invalid table name specified: %s', 16, 1, @TABLE_NAME);
    END;

    --parameterized query and added QUOTENAME
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT @ID = ID  
                FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE_NAME) + ' 
                WHERE CODE = @ERROR_CODE
                AND MESSAGE = @ERROR_MESSAGE 
                AND USER_ID = @USER_ID 
                AND CONTROLLER = @CONTROLLER 
                AND METHOD = @METHOD;';

    --execute parameterized query with @ID as OUTPUT parameter
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
        ,N'@ID INT OUTPUT
          ,@ERROR_MESSAGE VARCHAR(MAX)
          ,@ERROR_CODE VARCHAR(11)
          ,@USER_ID VARCHAR(50)
          ,@CONTROLLER VARCHAR(50) = NULL
          ,@METHOD VARCHAR(50)            '
        ,@ID = @ID OUTPUT
        ,@ERROR_MESSAGE = @ERROR_MESSAGE
        ,@ERROR_CODE = @ERROR_CODE --this will implicitly convert the int to varchar
        ,@USER_ID = @USER_ID
        ,@CONTROLLER = @CONTROLLER
        ,@METHOD = @METHOD;
    
    PRINT(@ID); --local variable will remain zero if no row was found

    SELECT @ERROR_CODE AS Code, @ERROR_MESSAGE AS MESSAGE;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    THROW;
END CATCH
GO
```